# how to split string and store it different variable

Tags: c

I need help as I am completely stuck here. Any idea for crictism will be very helpful.

I have string say  " cat-dog-animal"
and i want string like "dog-cat-animal"

I am slightly struck. I know in C i can use strtok , but that will break the string.
I AM wondering how to store that string in above format.

Thanks

Comment: Why the downvotes?  It's a reasonable rookie question, no?

Comment: You say in the title you will store it in a different variable, so does it matter that `strtok` will break the string?  Do you specifically need a solution that modifies the string in place?

Comment: Yes, I want something that modifies string .. I cant use any C++ lib so  I am really stuck and not getting any sol how to move ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat the first 2/3 of the string as a ring buffer and rotate the characters in it.

1. Find the index of the last dash
2. Save char at index
3. Move all preceding chars down one position
4. Restore saved char in step 2 to front of string.
5. Repeat steps 2 to 4 until the first dash is in the index position.

Granted it is not the most efficient solution, but it does work.
I'd post some actual code, but this sounds like homework.

---

Edit

```
#include <string.h>
void function( char * s )
{
    int second_dash = ( strrchr(s, '-') - s );

    do
    {
       char t = s[second_dash];
       memmove( s + 1, s, second_dash);
       s[0] = t;
    }
    while ( s[second_dash] != '-' );
 }
```

If your string library doesn't have strrchr() or memmove() they can be easily replaced by loops.

Comment: hi mocj, thanks for suggestion. but no its not homework.im so called professional and working in embedded system. I know very well how to do these things using vector or boost but unfortunately in my current task i cant use c++. so thats mainreason if some one canshow me sample code

Comment: God!!!! @mocj, the above code work flawlessly, thanks a lot for the help . you have saved me ........ cheers

Comment: hi mocj, could u please explain me a bit about  int second_dash = ( strrchr(s, '-') - s );

Comment: strrchr() is a reverse string search - so that function call searches for the last '-' in the string.  It returns a pointer to that character.  The returned pointer is subtracted from the pointer at the start of the string.  This gives the distance of the '-' character from the start of the string.  Since the data type is a single byte char this distance is also the index of the '-' char in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sscanf` and then rebuild the string from the 3 scanned substrings.

Comment: he might want an in-place solution given his "that will break the string" statement.

Comment: @Anrei: sscanf won't "break" the original string, but strtok will.

Comment: I know about strtok. i can split string but how to store it is my prob?

Comment: use strtok, create 3 substrings, rebuild the string from the three substrings.  Not sure why that's not a good solution.

Comment: it requires additional space, even if it doesn't break the original string